# Tutorials where I can start to master and fully grasp Java's Spring 2.5 + Hibernate (w/ some other frameworks)

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to fully master and fully grasp Java's Spring 2.5 and Hibernate framework for a limited amount of time (maybe in in less than 2 days?) and would like to ask this community if you can point out where I can start in mastering both frameworks. I kind of understand that it takes time to fully master both frameworks but would it be alright if you can point out tutorials where annotations, the xml mapping, and many of the basic things I need to grasp Spring and Hibernate are explained to a beginner who only tried to understand within the past couple of days?

I've tried googling bunch of times and wasted 3 days already trying to figure out and understand the concepts but it seems I understood nothing yet.

One of the major problems is that I could only use the following: Eclipse, Maven, Jetty, MySQL and can't use others like Tomcat or Ant, etc.

I'm using Linux Mint 10 / Ubuntu 10.10 in learning this in short time (yeah, I am in a limited amount of time @_@).

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Mastery usually takes longer than the time you have available.

Comment: Would it be alright to ask where you can direct me at least to a good reading where I can follow at least the basics where most of the things needed in both frameworks are pointed out? ^^;;

Comment: I am not familiar enough with Spring to be able to do so, sorry.  Considered asking Google for "spring tutorial"?

Comment: I did for the past few days but I ended up not understanding much ._. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Perhaps elaborating on "not understanding much (in the tutorial)" might be helpful for those whose advice you seek?

Comment: Keep up the sarcasm, Thorbjørn - at some point I'm SURE it will help.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Reference Documentation (for 2.5.x)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/) is a very good place to get an overview and examples on how to use the framework's features. I would recommend using a recent version of Spring, though (3.0.5 is the current stable release, 3.1 will be out soon).

The same goes for [the Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/) (choose your version there).

I know that reference docs are not that popular, but especially the Spring guys do great work putting together speaking examples. They also have [a blog post series called "Green Beans"](http://blog.springsource.com/index.php?s=green+beans) which introduces Spring features one by one. Maybe this should be your starting point, together with [their sample projects SVN repository](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/) - the "Petclinic" project uses Spring and Hibernate together.

Comment: +1 that. Incredibly helpful and nice to read! Really about everything you need to know, and integrating / using hibernate is explained as well

Comment: Thank you very much for the links :) I'm checking them out now :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [POJOs in Action](http://www.manning.com/crichardson/), by Chris Richardson. It's a few years old but it still covers what you need.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a ton of blogs and getting frustrated by all the different ways people suggest configuring these projects, I finally just created a very basic example project which integrates Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate and Ehcache. It also enables JMX easily. Take a look...

https://github.com/lookfirst/fallback

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend spring Frame work reference docs. secondly, download the Spring Source Code, set up the project, go thru the internals, try sample given with spring download, google help for spring samples or tutorials. 
You Will be the Master!